# which layout or view is used in this android application screenshot

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, view

[image: This is irctc mobile app screenshot]

I want to know about this view or layout , But I don't know how to search about this , so only I asked in this way , also I need to use in my mobile app

in this image there are 3 row , they are dynamically changeable and its from database, each rows have menu icon which is appears top right corner of each rows (3 dots) , they have a click event

please anyone can say which layout or view is this, how the dynamic records are shown like in this picture

Comment: It is a recycler view with repeated card views

Comment: simple `recycleview` with `custom adapter`

Answer (score 1):

It's a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) which loads the data to the UI using Custom Adapter. With your own custom adapter, you can inflate the view and fill the appropriate data into it.

Have a look at this [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview), You will understand better.